# Calculus-use ε-δ definition to prove certain limit

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x \to 27} x^{1/3}=(27^{1/3})$

let $x$ be $0<|x-27|< \delta$
What I have done is:
$|x^{1/3}-27^{1/3}|= |x-27|/|x^{2/3}+3x^{1/3}+9|$

And I was given the solution that sets $\delta=min(26,13\epsilon)$
I understand what it means but What I want to know is: is there any standard approach for solving this kind of question? like why we guess delta=26 in the first place?

thanks!

Comment: I think that you should try $0<x-27<\delta$ and $0<27-x<\delta$ separately.  It will make your derivation easier.

Comment: @mike Now I have this : 0<|x-27|<26 given in my answer, but Im not sure why delta set to be 26 in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not important what specific value you choose: You have only one goal:

$$|x^{1/3} - 27^{1/3}| < \epsilon .$$

And you choose $\delta$ so small to make this happen.

You know already that
$$|x^{1/3} - 27^{1/3}| = \frac{|x-27|}{x^{2/3} + 3x^{1/3} + 9}.$$

Note that you what to make a lower bound $C$ on $x$, so that

$$(*) \frac{|x-27|}{x^{2/3} + 3x^{1/3} + 9} \leq \frac{|x-27|}{C^{2/3} + 3C^{1/3} + 9}.$$

Then you want to choose a $C$ so that the term is easy to compute, so let's choose $C=1$. **Which means that $x\geq 1$, and that can be done if you choose $|x-27| \leq 26$**.

So you have

$$\frac{|x-27|}{x^{2/3} + 3x^{1/3} + 9} \leq \frac{|x-27|}{1 + 3 + 9} = \frac{|x-27|}{13}. $$

Now it's easy to make the RHS $\leq \epsilon$: Choose $\delta < 13\epsilon$.

So you see, the choice of that 26 only help you calculate $C^{2/3} + 3C^{1/3} + 9$ easier. You can as well choose another constant. For example, I choose $C = 0$. That is, $x\geq 0$. So I need that $|x-27|\leq 27$. Then if this is true, we have

$$\frac{|x-27|}{x^{2/3} + 3x^{1/3} + 9} \leq \frac{|x-27|}{9}. $$

So you see that we can also choose $\delta = \min\{ 27, 9\epsilon\}$.

Comment: I don quite understand why when choose C=1, then means X>=1?

Comment: We want to choose $C$ a lower bound for $x$, that is $x\geq C$. (So that (*) is true) @UnusualSkill

Comment: can I say like this? only when x>=1,then this inequality is true |x^2/3+3x^1/3+9|>1+3+9

Comment: @UnusualSkill: Yes, that's the same.

Comment: thx ur explanation is exactly what I want. Can you help me with this also?I cant understand others explanation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043490/prove-lim-x-to-ax0-6-a0-6-using-the-calculus-epsilon-delta-definitio/1043513#1043513

Comment: for your choice of C=0, |X^2/3+3X^1/3+9|>9 ,THEN x is not necessary have to be <=0 right? can be greater also, the inequality still holds true?

Comment: If $C = 0$, that main we choose $x\geq 0$, not $\leq 0$. @UnusualSkill

Comment: k thanks because u typo.@@how about another question, can u help?thx!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19058/discussion-between-unusualskill-and-john).